# How can I record my desktop into a "replay buffer", so I can replay the last x seconds?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Today I learned of a Windows-only product today called the [*Overwolf Replay HUD*](http://store.overwolf.com/app/Overwolf-Replay_HUD), which lets the user press a key to replay the last 20 seconds of happenings on their screen.  It's meant for people playing or spectating fast-paced videogames who want to quickly review a hectic moment.

I'm trying to duplicate that behaviour on Linux.  So far, I figure I could easily start `ffmpeg` (with `-f x11grab`) capture to a file in `/tmp` (which is memory-mapped), then use [`sxhkd`](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) to bind a keyboard shortcut to launch [`mpv`](https://mpv.io/) to play the last 20 seconds of that file.

However, the rest of the recording would still be stored, and I'd eventually run out of RAM.  How could I go about keeping only the last 20 seconds?

Comment: Some promising leads from reading around: ⓐ Open Broadcaster Software's internal ffmpeg fork has [a replay buffer feature](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-classic-how-to-use-the-replay-buffer.103/) implemented [in this commit](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/commit/f2e85b83529778e4d3fa58b55443a28799c8fdd6). ⓑ Vanilla ffmpeg's [`-segment` & co.](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples-9) can split a stream into separate files of specified length, which could just be pruned periodically to save space, but this may require rejoining files before playing them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The segment muxer will work.

**Step 1**:

```
ffmpeg -i input force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*4) -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_wrap 6 -segment_list list.m3u8 -segment_list_size 6 seg%d.ts
```

This will save the recording in segments of 4 seconds. Once 6 segments have been written, the next segment will overwrite the first file. The playlist is updated accordingly.

**Step 2**:

```
ffmpeg -i list.m3u8 -c copy video.mp4
```

or

```
ffplay list.m3u8
```

The duration of the preserved footage is `20 < duration < 24`.

Answer (score 1):

OBS has a configurable replay buffer feature, that covers exactly what you want.